# Tagged Deck of Cards

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Here's a recent problem I stumbled upon:

A deck of cards contains $2n$ distinct cards. There are $n$ different tags. Each tag is put onto two different cards. Two cards form a *pair* if and only if they have the same tagging. Suppose you play the following game with the cards: you take the first card in the deck, remove it, and start a new pile of cards. You take the second card, remove it, and put it into the pile with the first card. You continue to do this. When you get a pair of cards in the pile, you immediately remove both cards from that pair from the pile and throw them into the trash. The game ends when all the cards in the deck have been removed. How many of the $(2n)!$ orderings of the cards will have at most $2$ cards at any given time in the pile?

Clearly for $n=1$ and $n=2$ all $(2n)!$ orderings work. At first, I thought that a recursion could take care of the problem, but there is no obvious way to link $n$ and $n+1$. Obviously, the goal is to have an ordering where pairs come in such a way that there are never more than $2$ cards in the pile, but I don't know how to count this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n$ denote the number of ways you can order the $2n$ cards such that at no moment there are more than $2$ cards in the pile.

Assume we have $n$ cards and let the first card be tagged as $A$. Then we have two cases. If the second card is $A$ then we have that there are $n \cdot a_{n-1}$ ways to shuffle the next $2(n-1)$ cards such that the condition is satisfied, as we have $n$ options for the removed pair.

If the second card is tagget as $B$ then we have only two options for the third card. It's either tagged $A$ or $B$, as otherwise there will be three cards in the pile. In any case we get rid of any pair and then we can return the remaining card on top of our pile and we're again in the case with $2(n-1)$ cards. Therefore there are $n \cdot 2a_{n-1}$ ways from this case, one when the third card is $A$ and the one when the third one is $B$ and there are $n$ options for the removed pair.

As we've considered all the possible cases we can conclude that $a_n = n\cdot 3a_{n-1}$ and $a_2 = \binom{4}{2,2} =6$

---

To be more clear there are three possible "families" of shufles, namely $AAxx \dots xx$, $AxAxx \dots xx$, $xAAxx \dots xx$. There are $n$ options for the pair tagged by $A$ and there are $a_{n-1}$ options for how the $x$'s are tagged. So $a_n = n\cdot 3a_{n-1}; \forall n \ge 3$